# Having Issue On PHP MVC File Connections

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PHP MVC App which has a file structure like this
[image]

in `init.php` I have

```
<?php
include('app/Database.php');
include('app/models/m_template.php');
include('app/models/m_categories.php');

$Database = new Database();
$Template = new Template();
$Categories = new Categories($Database);
```

in `m_tenplate.php` I have `Template()` class like this to load files.

```
class Template
{

    function __construct() {}

    public function load($url, $title = '')
    {
        if ($title != '') { $this->set_data('page_title', $title); }
        include($url);
    }
```

and in m_vcategories.php I have Categoty() class like

```
class Categories {
    function __construct() {}

    public function test(){
        echo 'This is Test';
    }
```

in index.php I have

```
<?php
include 'app/init.php';
$Template->load('app/views/v_home.php');
```

now when I try to access the Categories() methods through `v_home.php` in Views like:

```
<?php
$Categories->test();
```

I am getting following errors

[image]

can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: You include the v_home.php in you template load method. In this context you cannot access $Categories. This variable is not defined in method load. As a quick and dirty fix you can set $Categories as global in your load method and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Categories` is outside of the `load` methods scope, which also means it is out of scope for any files included within the `load` methods body.

Here is a solution which you could use to work around this:

```
// Add a $variables parameter to your load method.
public function load($url, $title = '', $variables=NULL)
{
    if( is_array($variables) )
    {
        foreach( $variables as $key => $item )
        {
            $$key = $item;
        }
    }
    if ($title != '') { $this->set_data('page_title', $title); }
    include($url);
}
```

Then you use the load method like this:

```
<?php
include 'app/init.php';
$Template->load('app/views/v_home.php', '', array('Categories' => $Categories);
```

You put an associative array of items you would like to make available to the template page.

Comment: Hi lshas thanks for comment I updated the code as you said but still getting same error

Comment: @Behseini Sorry, was an error. Fixed it now, I forgot to add the '', between $url and $variables. Should work fine if you try it now.

Comment: Thanks again lshas, can you please let me know what the method is doing exactly?!

Comment: The code I added lets you pass variables through the third parameter of load. That should be an associative array which have the variable names as the key, and their values as the item. This will make all the variables passed through available in the load-methods scope.

Answer (score 1):

The variable **categories** isn't available at v_home scope, to achieve this you need to add new parameter to your Template class - in **load** method and extract the contents of that variable, it will be like this

```
public function load($url, $title = '',$data = array())
{
    extract($data);
    if ($title != '') { $this->set_data('page_title', $title); }
    include($url);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

then in index.php you can do this

```
<?php
include 'app/init.php';
$Template->load('app/views/v_home.php','',array('Categories' => $Categories));
```

or

```
<?php
include 'app/init.php';
$Template->load('app/views/v_home.php','',compact('Categories'));
```

Comment: Thanks Solaiman, but I am still getting this errors `Notice: Undefined variable: Categories in C:\wamp\www\project1\app\views\v_home.php on line 2` and `Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\project1\app\views\v_home.php on line 2`

Comment: Sorry for that, i forget to pass the title, i've edit it now. check it